# What does min |expression| mean?

Tags: calculus, newton-raphson

Hello I am doing some problems from Calculus, in the Newton's method, and it says to compute the $\min|f'(x)|\ \ (-1 <= x <= 1)$

My $f(x)$ is $x^3/2 - 2x^2 + 3x +2$, then my $f'(x)$ is $3x^2/2 - 4x + 3$

But I do not understand what this "min" is and how to I have to find it? ($x$ can be from $[-1, 1]$)

Comment: i think min means the minimum over $x$ of your function

Comment: So for which X (in the range -1 to 1) my function output has the lowest value, and also does this mean that the value should be always positive since there is absolute value?

Comment: i think no, the lowest value can also be negative if you mean $|f(x)|$ then this value can also be greater than zero or equal to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial in $x$, and the extremum of a quadratic polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ is attained at $x=-\dfrac b{2a}$.

Its value is $\dfrac{4ac-b^2}{4a}$, and it is a *minimum* if $a>0$, a *maximum* if $a<0$.

Now this minimum is here attained at $x=\dfrac43>1$, so the function is *decreasing* on the interval $[-1,1]$, so the minimum on this interval is attained at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your book means $\min(\vert f'(x)\vert: x \in [-1,1])$.

This means **the lowest value of $f'(x)$** that you can get if you choose $x$ in the given interval. Finding the minimum of a function with calculus takes a few steps -- have you seen the "first derivative test" before? You are going to want to use it here to minimize $f'(x)$. First you need to find the points where $\frac{d}{dx} f'(x) = 0$. Your minimum will be at one of these points, **or** at one of the endpoints of the interval, so you need to check the value of $f'(x)$ at all of them. Do these steps make sense?

Comment: Okay but there is no real solution to 3/2 x^2 - 4x + 3 = 0 ?? What should I do

Comment: differentiate again?

Comment: If I differentiate again, then the second derivative = 0, I get x = 4/3 which is higher than the [-1,1], I think that my min here should be -1 !?

Comment: What are the values of $f'$ at $-1$ and $1$?

Comment: f ' (-1) = 8.5  & f ' (1) = 1/2, therefore 1/2 is the min, right?